# App scrolling issue in Android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, scroll

I have developed an app in JQuery Mobile with the help of intel XDK IDE. 
The app is working well in some phone. but in some other phones its having a scrolling issue , that is users are unable to scroll.
What may be the possible cause of this problem?
and do I really need to embed any third party library like iscroll?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its hard to say but i suggest if you are using the latest version of JQM is to drop back a few JQM versions like 1.4.4,3,2 and see if you get the same problem

Comment: Mostly the mistakes are: Wrong viewport, unclean HTML and unclean JS.

Comment: @Joerg May I know what do you mean by unclean JS or HTML ??